# How to refresh a component which is already present in stack after navigating from another component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Ex- I have two components A and B. I need to refresh component A after navigating from component B.

componentDid Mount doesn't work because A is already mounted.

How to achieve this. I am using react navigation to navigate from B->A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can add a listener for the same in react native.*

There are total 4 listners for the same.

1. **willFocus** - the screen will focus
2. **didFocus** - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
3. **willBlur** - the screen will be unfocused
4. **didBlur** - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

Try the below code

```
componentDidMount(){
    const didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      payload => {
        console.warn('didFocus ', payload);
        # just write your code/call a method here which you want to execute when the app comes from a component
        this.handleRefresh()
      }
    );
}
```

Dont forget to remove it when it is done.

```
componentWillMount(){
    didFocusSubscription.remove();
}
```

More you can read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle). Thanks :)

Comment: component is already mounted (present in stack). I need to go A->B and B->A (refresh A). Also componentWillMount is deprecated

Comment: use componentDidMount() instead...yeah to do this, if you are navigating back to another component. Alternatively you can clear the stack if you did'nt want to add the listner

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `NavigationEvents` from `react-navigation` or can pass a callback which will trigger on `navigation.goBack()`.

**Check this snack :** [Temporary Link](https://snack.expo.io/@dhavaljardosh/update-on-navigation.goback()?platform=android&name=First%20navigation&dependencies=react-navigation%40%5E4.0.10%2Creact-navigation-tabs%40%5E2.5.6%2Creact-navigation-stack%40%5E1.10.3%2Creact-navigation-drawer%40%5E2.3.3&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F4.x%2Fnew-screen.js)